# Every function can $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ can be represented as the sum of two one-to-one functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transfinite-induction

How can one use the Principle of Transfinite Induction, i.e, "Let $P(z)$ be a mathematical statement that depends on the ordinal $z$. Suppose whenever $P(\eta)$ is true $\forall \eta<z,P(z)$ is also true. Then $P(z)$ is true for every ordinal $z$." To prove that every function

$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

can be represented by as the sum of two one-to-one functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Fix an enumeration $(x_i \mid i < 2^{\aleph_0})$ of $\mathbb R$.

*Claim.* There exists a sequence $(g_\xi \mid \xi \le 2^{\aleph_0})$ such that for all $\xi \le 2^{\aleph_0}$

- $g_\xi \colon \{x_i \mid i < \xi \} \to \mathbb R$ is a function,
- $g_\zeta \subseteq g_\xi$ for all $\zeta \le \xi$ and
- $f \restriction \{ x_i \mid i < \xi \} - g_\xi \colon \{x_i \mid i < \xi \} \to \mathbb R$ is one-to-one.

Then $g := g_{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is as desired.

Prove the claim by induction on $\xi \le 2^{\aleph_0}$. At limit steps $g_\xi$ is the union of all the previous defined functions. At successor steps you need to shift the value of $f(x_{\xi-1})$ to a value that hasn't already been used.

Comment: This outline is a bit weird in the sense that the transfinite induction is only used to show that a certain recursive construction is possible... I'm pretty sure that this is not the intended way to approach this problem, assuming this is some sort of exercise that was presented to you. But then again, right now I don't see how a more natural application of transfinite induction to this problem would look like. Maybe someone else will chime in.